# How to do a significance test on the performance of four classifiers on two different test sets?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, classification, statistical-significance, natural-language

I'm trying to find out if an authorship obfuscation technique leads to a statistically significant drop in authorship classification performance.

To test this assumption, I have a dataset of texts split into a training set ($t_{train}$) and a test set ($t_{test}$). I then produce an obfuscated version of $t_{test}$. Let's call that obfuscated version $t_{obf}$.

I setup four different classifiers (each trained on $t_{train}$) and use them to predict the authors of:

1. The non-obfuscated test set $t_{test}$.
2. The obfuscated test set $t_{obf}$.

This gives me a 4x2 matrix of (weighted) results. I'm using Accuracy here for illustration purposes but this could also be any other metric (e.g. F1).

| Classifier | Accuracy on $t_{test}$ | Accuracy on $t_{obf}$ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0.7 | 0.2 |
| B | 0.5 | 0.3 |
| C | 0.4 | 0.3 |
| D | 0.7 | 0.5 |

What is a good way to test if the observed drop in classification performance on the obfuscated test set has statistical significance? I was thinking of a Wilcoxon Signed Rank Test but from what I understand I would need more result pairs (i.e. more classifiers) for that.

To be clear, I don't want to compare the classifiers among each other. I want to test if the obfuscation has a statistically significant impact on the classification performance across these classifiers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more easily done using your raw data: the number of correct and incorrect classifications, for each version of the test set, for each classifier.

A simple approach would be to run four chi-squared tests on the contingency tables for each classifier, e.g.

```
|            | Test | Obf |
| N Correct  | a    | b   |
| N Incorrect| c    | d   |
```

which would give you a p-value for each classifier.

A more complete approach would be to use multilevel logistic regression, with estimates allowed to vary between classifiers are random effects, e.g., (using the `lme4` package for R):

```
model = glmer(accuracy ~ 1 + set + (1 + set | classifier), 
              data = your_data, family = binomial)`
```

where your data has one row per classification case, and set is either `'test'` or `'obf'`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Eoin! That helps a lot. If I do the four chi-squared tests and end up with four p-values—one per classifier—how would you recommend I best report the results? Is it advisable to do something like Fisher's method to combine the p-values and then only report that combined p-value?

Comment: If you want to combine the results, use the second approach. This will give you estimates and standard errors for each classifier, as well as an overall estimate, SE, and p-value.

Comment: Thanks @Eoin! Assuming I go with the chi-squared test, what are the requirements for my raw data? Does it need to follow a certain distribution?